# how to delete the duplicate lines in file except the first matched line

Tags: bash, shell, perl, sed

In the following configuration file

```
/etc/fine-tune.conf
```

We have duplicate lines as

```
clean_history_in_os=true
```

we want to delete all the lines that include **clean_history_in_os=true**
except the first matched line in the file

what I did until now is that

```
  sed  -i '/clean_history_in_os=true/d' /etc/fine-tune.conf
```

but the problem is that sed delete all "clean_history_in_os=true" lines

I will happy to get ideas to solve this issue ,

Comment: You want to delete all duplicates or just `clean_history_in_os`?

Comment: only according to the requested line ( in this example I want to delete the duplicate   line - clean_history_in_os=true ) , but this is example , it could be different line

Comment: `awk '!a[$0]++' file`

Comment: @Cyrus not good option because - its delete all duplicate lines and what we want is only to delete specific duplicate line , second its delete also the empty lines

Comment: I posted a Perl answer even though the awk one by anybhava is good, because you specifically asked -- but if you wanted Perl or sed then why tag the question with awk as well?

Comment: yes you right , I tag awk because I was thinking that awk can also update the file as ( sed -i ) , now I see that option isnt in awk and I not have awk gnu , so I will delete this tag

Comment: @zdim , your perl answer is really excellent , I need to check this option on my machine to see if all options can be supported

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Perl

```
perl -i -ne'next if /clean_history_in_os=true/ && ++$ok > 1; print' file
```

This increments the counter when on that line and if `> 1` it skips the line, otherwise prints

---

The question came up of how to pass the pattern to Perl if we have it as a shell variable.  Below I assume that the shell variable `$VAR` contains the string `clean_history...`

In all this a shell variable's value is directly used as a pattern in a regex. If it's the literal string from the question then the code below goes as given. However, if there may be special characters they should be escaped; so you may want to precede the pattern with `\Q` when used in regex. As a general note, one should take care to not use input from the shell to run code (say under `/e`).

- Pass it as an argument, which is then available in [@ARGV](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@ARGV)

  ```
  perl -i -ne'
      BEGIN { $qr=shift; }; 
      next if /$qr/ && ++$ok > 1; print
  ' "$VAR" file
  ```

  where the [`BEGIN` block](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END) runs in the `BEGIN` phase, before runtime (so not for the following iterations). In it [shift](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) removes the first element from `@ARGV`, which in the above invocation is the value in `$VAR`, first interpolated by shell. Then the filename `file` remains in `@ARGV`, so available for processing under `-n` (file is opened and its lines iterated over)
- Use the [`-s` switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches), which enables command-line switches for the program

  ```
  perl -i -s -ne'next if /$qr/ && ++$ok > 1; print' -- -qr="$VAR" file
  ```

  The `--` (after the one-line program under `''`) marks the start of arguments for the program; then `-qr` introduces a variable `$qr` into the program, with a value assigned to it as above (with just `-qr` the variable `$qr` gets value `1`, so is a flag).

  Any such options must come before possible filenames, and they are removed from `@ARGV` so the program can then normally process the submitted files.
- Export the bash variable, making it an environment variable which can then be accessed in the Perl program via [`%ENV` hash](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%ENV)

  ```
  export VAR="clean_history..."
  perl -i -ne'next if /$ENV{VAR}/ && ++$ok > 1; print' file
  ```

  Or, if `$VAR` is used only in this command, can use the shorter (must be all on one line)

  ```
  VAR="clean_history..."  perl -i -ne'...' file
  ```

  I would rather recommend either of the first two options, over this one.

These are ways to pass input to a Perl program entered entirely on the command-line (*one-liner*), without `STDIN` or files.  With a script better use a library, in the first place [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html).

---

A refinement of the question given in a comment specifies that if the phrase `clean_...` starts with a `#` then that line should be skipped altogether. It's simplest to separately test for that

```
next if /#$qr/; next if /$qr/ && ++$ok > 1; print
```

or, relying on short-circuiting

```
next if /#$qr/ || (/$qr/ && ++$ok > 1); print
```

The first version is less error prone and probably clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `awk` to delete all matching lines except the first one:

```
awk '!(/clean_history_in_os=true/ && n++)' file
```

To save file in place you can use this `gnu awk` command:

```
awk -i inplace '!(/clean_history_in_os=true/ && n++)' file
```

otherwise use temporary file as:

```
awk '!(/clean_history_in_os=true/ && n++)' file > $$.tmp && mv $$.tmp file
```

---

Here is one `sed` solution to do the same:

```
sed -i -n '0,/clean_history_in_os=true/p;/clean_history_in_os=true/!p' file
```

Comment: I prefer to work with sed  or perl , because I can edit the file with ( -i ) option , with awk I not able to edit the file as sed -i    , or perl -i ,

Comment: in `awk` just output to a temp file and `mv` the temp file: `awk '$0=="clean_history_in_os=true"{c[$0]++} c[$0]<2; ' conf > tmp && mv tmp conf`

Comment: yes I know thx but I prefer to avoid that , because some time I need to delete around 10 duplicate lines so this approach is not so clean in case we have a lot of duplicate lines

Comment: If using `gnu awk`, you can use `-i inplace`

Comment: I guess in my case we not have this option , ( awk -i inplace ) , so I will happy to get solution with sed / perl one liner

Comment: Using the range command in sed i.e. `1,/../` will not work if the regexp is on the first line. GNU sed has a specific `0,/../` range will take care of this problem. An alternative solution is `sed '/clean_history_in_os=true/{x;/./{x;d};g;x}' file` which keeps a counter in the hold space.

Comment: @Ed I think your solution is the best , but still this isnt update the file itself

Comment: You've already been told in the comments how to update the original file, just like with any other command: `awk 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file`. Having said that `sed -i` is GNU sed only so it's hard to believe you have GNU sed and perl but you don't have or can't get GNU awk (for `awk -i inplace`).

Comment: What's the error with `sed` command? I have tested my updated `sed` answer and it worked fine. @EdMorton: `awk '!(/clean_history_in_os=true/ && n++)'` is really smart