# pass an argument from bash to perl without use of ARGV

Tags: bash, perl, xargs

Very simple question (I think) that I'm surprised I can't seem to find an answer to.  So I have the following so far:

```
£ perl -ne 'print if /ENGPacific Beach\s\s/' 15AM171H0N15000GAJK5 \
| perl -ane 'print "$F[1]|";END{print "\0"}' | xargs -i -0 echo {}
    3346|10989|95459|139670|2239329|3195595|3210017|
```

So....the first pipe is because the file is 1.5G, so not doing record separation initially greatly speeds things up.  The `xargs` part is to demonstrate what I'm trying to do.  Which is basically the following

```
| xargs -i perl --setperlvar pipeContents={} -ane 'print if $F[3] =~ /$pipeContents/' 15AM171H0N15000GAJK5
```

1) I know I could use ARGV in a script.  I know the whole thing should just be a single script.  Let's ignore those bits. My love for `-n` knows no bounds.

2) Sorry I couldn't find this myself..I'm sure it's incredibly obvious...I did some digging in perldoc and found nothing, though.

3) I'd be interested in a bash/zsh solution that forces the `{}` to be interpreted by the shell in the middle of the perl ticks as well.

Comment: I am not sure of all that's involved in your pipeline, but see three ways to pass arguments from bash to Perl one-liner in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51713578/4653379)

Comment: Proposal (3) is a source of major security vulnerabilities. Actually-exploited-in-the-real-world security vulnerabilities -- search for "shell injection"; injecting data as code into a perl interpreter is just as bad as injecting it into a shell. Don't do that, *especially* when you're processing 1.5GB of data and can't read through it by hand to find any `"+system("rm -rf ~")+"` substrings.

Comment: (For that matter, `xargs` without `-0` or `-d $'\n'` is also considered bad practice in the bash world for some rather good reasons; see [the "Actions in Bulk" section of Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions_in_bulk:_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B-)).

Comment: Is `--setvar` a thing, or something you made up?

Comment: --setvar is a thing I made up to demonstrate what I'm trying to do. The data is 100% trusted and this is a "one-shot" program I'm using to search data. @zdim I think proposal 2  answers my question.  I don't believe the question itself is a duplicate so if you want to post as answer I'll accept. Any edits to my question to improve searchability are welcome.

Comment: And @CharlesDuffy agree. I was being sloppy and I'll fix. I trust the data (and know how it is formatted) but no reason not to use -0

Comment: @zzxyz  That may be a good idea since the title is crystal clear (while that one is a different business).  However, there is more involved here and I am still not quite sure of it all -- do you mean: by `--setvar` to indicate that you want some way to "set a var", which would be the shell variable `pipeContents`, which would be set to the current phrase processed by `xargs` (is that what `{}` do here?) ... ?  That's quite a bit rolled into one :)  I can't suggest another way since I'm also unsure of the whole context; is `xargs` crucial here or not?

Comment: Re "*3)*", You mean like `echo abc | xargs -i perl -E'say "<{}>"'`? Well, it "works" (because `xargs` sees two string, `perl` and `-Esay "<{}>"`, and it replaces all instances of `{}` in those strings), but don't do that. Generating Perl code from the shell is a BAD idea.

Comment: I just realized ikegami and Charles Duffy were referring to *my* proposal #3, and not option #3 from zdim's link.  Fair enough, and the `-s` option keeps that from being desirable.

Comment: @zdim - Regarding clarifying my question, you may have figured it out, but `xargs -i`.  Well, create a directory with 3 files and then do `find . -print0 | xargs -0 echo hello` and `find . -print0 | xargs -0 -i echo {} hello`  Two things.  It allows you to put the pipe "output" wherever.  It has the side-effect of `-n1`, which, for example, has the side-effect of causing perl to output correct file line numbers with `$.` ...and slowing perl WAY down if there are a ton of files.

Comment: thank you for explanation -- yes, I know `xargs` but I wasn't sure whether it was integral to what you want, or used only to "_demonstrate..._". I also wasn't sure what altogether the goal was.  But it's all good now, you've got a _really thorough_ analysis from ikegami :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two notes before I start:

- The trailing `|` in the pattern will cause every line to match. It needs to be removed.
- `/3346|10989|95459|139670|2239329|3195595|3210017/` will match `9993346`, so you need to anchor the pattern.

Fixes for these problems are present in all of the following solutions.

---

You can pass data to a program through

- Argument list
- Environment
- An open file descriptor (e.g. stdin, but fd 3 or higher could also be used) to a pipe
- External storage (file, database, memcache daemon, etc)

You can still use the argument list. You just need to remove the argument from `@ARGV` before the loop starts by using `BEGIN` or avoiding `-n`.

```
perl -ne'print if /ENGPacific Beach\s\s/' 15AM171H0N15000GAJK5 |
perl -ane'push @p, $F[1]; END { print join "|", @p; }' |
xargs -i perl -ane'
    BEGIN { $p = shift(@ARGV); }
    print if $F[3] =~ /^(?:$p)\z/;
' {} 15AM171H0N15000GAJK5
```

Perl also has a built-in argument parsing function in the form of `-s` you could utilize.

```
perl -ne'print if /ENGPacific Beach\s\s/' 15AM171H0N15000GAJK5 |
perl -ane'push @p, $F[1]; END { print join "|", @p; }' |
xargs -i perl -sane'print if $F[3] =~ /^(?:$p)\z/' -- -p={} 15AM171H0N15000GAJK5
```

`xargs` doesn't seem to have an option to set an environment variable, so taking that approach gets a little complicated.

```
perl -ne'print if /ENGPacific Beach\s\s/' 15AM171H0N15000GAJK5 |
perl -ane'push @p, $F[1]; END { print join "|", @p; }' |
xargs -i sh -c '
    P="$1" perl -ane'\''print if $F[3] =~ /^(?:$ENV{P})\z/'\'' 15AM171H0N15000GAJK5
' dummy {}
```

It's weird to involve `xargs` for a single line. If we avoid `xargs`, we can turn the above (ugly) command inside out, giving something quite nice.

```
P="$(
    perl -ne'print if /ENGPacific Beach\s\s/' 15AM171H0N15000GAJK5 |
    perl -ane'push @p, $F[1]; END { print join "|", @p; }'
)" perl -ane'print if $F[3] =~ /^(?:$ENV{P})\z/' 15AM171H0N15000GAJK5
```

By the way, you don't need a second `perl` to split only the matching lines.

```
P="$(
    perl -ne'
       push @p, (split)[1] if /ENGPacific Beach\s\s/;
       END { print join "|", @p; }
    ' 15AM171H0N15000GAJK5
)" perl -ane'print if $F[3] =~ /^(?:$ENV{P})\z/' 15AM171H0N15000GAJK5
```

That said, I think using `$ENV{P}` repeatedly should be avoided to speed things up.

```
P=... perl -ane'print if $F[3] =~ /^(?:$ENV{P})\z/o' 15AM171H0N15000GAJK5
```

From there, I see two possible speed improvements. (Test to be sure.)

1. Avoiding splitting entirely in the last `perl`.

   ```
   P=... perl -ne'
      BEGIN { $re = qr/^(?:\S+\s+){3}(?:$ENV{P})\s/o; }
      print if /$re/o;
   ' 15AM171H0N15000GAJK5
   ```
2. Avoiding regular expressions entirely in the last `perl`.

   ```
   P=... perl -ane'
      BEGIN { %h = map { $_ => 1 } split /\|/, $ENV{P} }
      print if $h{$F[3]};
   ' 15AM171H0N15000GAJK5
   ```

Comment: I'm gonna be a day or so processing this answer:)  Regarding bulletpoint #2...it's a great point.  I really don't even need a regex for the last bit...Just a straight compare or "string begins with".  That said, a few extra results are fine.  They are going to a terminal, where I'm inspecting them by hand.  I'm basically looking at a text dump of a SQL-style database...manually inspecting the data, more or less.

Comment: kudos on the detail in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A handy way to pass arguments is via the [`-s` switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches), which enables command-line switches for the program

```
perl -s -E'say $var' -- -var=value
```

The `--` after the program marks the start of arguments for the program. Then `-var` introduces a variable `$var` into the program, with a value for it supplied after `=`; what is there is expanded by the shell first. With just `-var` the variable `$var` gets value `1`.

Any such options must come before possible filenames, and they are removed from `@ARGV` so the program can normally process the submitted files

```
perl -s -ne'...' -- -var="$SHELL_VAR" filename
```

where `-var={}` works, too. In some shells  (`tcsh` for one) it may need be escaped, `\{\}`.

However, I also think that it'd be better to not go to `xargs`. See [ikegami's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51831085/4653379) for an extremely rounded discussion and various ways, as well as their comment beneath this post for how to avoid it with `-s`.

Comment: Good idea. Added `-s` to my answer. (heh, `perl -sane`) Still think avoiding `xargs` is the way to go, though. But you can still do that with `-s` by changing `P="$( ... )" perl -ane'...$ENV{P}...' filename` into `perl -sane'...$p...' -- -p="$( ... )" filename`

Comment: @ikegami Absolutely agree on `xargs`. (I think that they have it only as a way to show what they want?) I didn't discuss anything else because of your absolutely exhaustive answer. I think I'd still leave this post since it provides details on `-s`.