# Perl Pack Unpack on Shell Variable

Tags: bash, shell, perl, pack, unpack

Ultimately my goal is to convert a hexdump of data to the correct floating point value. I have set up my shell script to isolate the individual hex values I need to look at and arrange them in the correct order for a little Endian float conversion.

To simplify everything, I'll bypass the code I have managed to get working, and I'll start with:

```
rawHex=0x41000000
echo $(perl -e 'print unpack "f", pack "L", $ENV{rawHex}')
```

When I execute this code, the result is 0. However if I were to execute the code without attempting to pull the value of the shell variable:

```
echo $(perl -e 'print unpack "f", pack "L", 0x41000000')
```

The result is 8, which is what I am expecting.

I'd appreciate any help on how I can update my Perl expression to properly interpret the value of the shell variable. Thanks.

Comment: The variable you define in the shell is "local," not an "environment" variable so it isn't seen by `%ENV`.  You need to "export" it, `export rawHex=...` (or just `export rawHex` if it's already been set up).  Now `%ENV` will have it.  (Alternatively, you can pass it to your Perl command-line program, as a command line argument or a switch)

Comment: I attempted to verify that the variable was accessible this way by evaluating:```echo $(perl -e 'print $ENV{rawHex}')``` and the result was 0x41000000 as expected.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55753111/4653379) for the explanation and then [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58705112/4653379) (with its links) should be useful, too

Comment: (to round off these comments: you also need [hex](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex.html). It's now all done in ikegami's answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
export rawHex=0x41000000
perl -le'print unpack "f", pack "L", hex($ENV{rawHex})'
```

---

As you discovered, your code isn't equivalent to the following:

```
perl -e 'print unpack "f", pack "L", 0x41000000'
```

Your code is equivalent to the following:

```
perl -e 'print unpack "f", pack "L", "0x41000000"'
```

Like `"0x41000000"`, `$ENV{rawHex}` produces the *string* `0x41000000`. On the other hand, `0x41000000` produces the *number* one billion, ninety million, five hundred nineteen thousand and forty.

To convert the hex representation of a number into the number it represents, one uses `hex`. Simply replace `$ENV{rawHex}` with `hex($ENV{rawHex})`.

```
export rawHex=0x41000000
perl -le'print unpack "f", pack "L", hex($ENV{rawHex})'
```

The `-l` causes a line feed to be added to the output so you don't need to use `echo`. Feel free to remove the `l` if you're not actually using `echo`

Generating code (as suggested in the earlier answer) is a horrible practice.

Answer (score 1):

A working solution is

```sh
rawHex=0x41000000
echo $(perl -e "print unpack 'f', pack 'L', ${rawHex}")
```

Your code has two problems. The first is that in bash, variables between single quotes `'` will not be evaluated. That's why I inverted single and double quotes in your example.

The second problem is the use of `ENV`. I am not sure why you use it, but you don't need it.

Comment: I had tried a permutation of this, but I had an unnecessary set of parentheses, and it was not returning a consistent result. Now that I've removed the parentheses, it's working. Thank you!

Comment: Remember to accept my answer if it solved your problem ;)

Comment: While this is correct technically (it'll work) I'll have to speak against "injection" -- it opens the whole (Perl one-line) script to who-knows-what.  There are other ways to pass a shell variable to a program, one by `export`-ing whereby it becomes an "environment" variable and can be accessed in `%ENV`

Comment: Re "*variables between single quotes ' will not be evaluated.*", That's a good thing. Generating code is not a good idea.