# How can I add variables into my Perl one-liner?

Tags: perl, variables, command-line, scripting, command-line-arguments

I've got the following one-liner with Perl:

```
perl -MLingua::EN::Sentence=get_sentences -ne 'print "$_\n" for grep { /replace_me/i } @{get_sentences($_)}' "${filePath}"
```

How can I restructure this so that I'm able to replace the "replace_me" section with any string of text (aka, a variable) that I can pass into the script as an argument?

I understand that you cannot add variables within single quotes, but I'm not sure how to restructure this at the moment with double quotes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the `-s` option to pass variables `perl`, for example `perl -sE 'say $foo' -- -foo=Foo`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A "one-liner" is a program that can take input like any other -- what is passed to the program at invocation is in `@ARGV` array.

Then there are two particular issues to take into account

- With `-n` the code under `''` is the body of a loop (over lines from the files that are processed or from `STDIN`) so you want to extract your input (arguments) in a `BEGIN` block, before the runtime and so before the loop starts
- Arguments that are passed to the script must be removed from `@ARGV` so that what remains are only filename(s), to be read line by line (under `-n`, or `-p`)

Then there are three ways to bring arguments into the program.

Fetch the arguments from `@ARGV` by hand

```
perl -wnE'BEGIN { $input = shift };  ... '  "input string" filename(s)
```

where `...` stand for your code, just as it was, but which now can use `$input`.

Another way is with [`-s` switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) which enables a rudimentary mechanism for arguments

```
perl -s -wnE'...code using $input...' -- -input="input string"  filename(s)
```

where the name given after `-` (I used `input` above) is the name of the variable in which input gets stored.  The `--` are there to mark the beginning of the arguments.  All arguments passed to the script must be given before the filename(s).

Finally, instead of passing arguments directly we can set a [shell variable](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html) which the script will then see. In `bash` shell we can do it in the same command-line, right before the command itself

```
input="input string"  perl -wnE'...$ENV{input}...' filenames
```

Or, set it up beforehand and `export` it

```
export input="input string"
perl -wnE'... $ENV{input} ...'
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51713578/4653379) for details on all three ways.

Once this input is used in a regex escape it using [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html), `/...\Q$input\E.../i`, unless it is meant to be a ready regex pattern.  Please see the linked documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There are three primary ways of passing information to Perl without using STDIN or external storage.

- Arguments

  ```
  perl -ne'BEGIN { $text=shift(@ARGV) } print if /\Q$text/i' -- "$text"
  ```
- Command-line options

  In a full program, you'd use [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt::Long), but [`perl -s`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) will do fine here.

  ```
  perl -sne'print if /\Q$text/i' -- -text="$text" --
  ```
- Environment variables

  ```
  TEXT="$text" perl -ne'print if /\Q$ENV{TEXT}/i' --
  ```

---

In your case, you could use the following:

```sh
perl -ne'
   use Lingua::EN::Sentence qw( get_sentences );
   CORE::say for grep { /\Q$text/i } @{ get_sentences($_) };
' -- -text="$text" -- "$filePath"
```

I used `/Q$text/i` instead of `/$text/i` because I assumed the input is text to find rather than a regex pattern. `\Q..\E` converts text into a pattern that will match that text. (The `\E` is optional at the end of the literal.)

Answer (score -1):

Provided that you have `REPLACEMENT` environment variable defined:

```
export REPLACEMENT=replace_me
```

You should be able to do either:

```
perl -MLingua::EN::Sentence=get_sentences -ne 'print "$_\n" for grep { /'$REPLACEMENT'/i } @{get_sentences($_)}' "${filePath}"
```

or:

```
perl -MLingua::EN::Sentence=get_sentences -ne 'print "$_\n" for grep { /$ENV{REPLACEMENT}/i } @{get_sentences($_)}' "${filePath}"
```

It probably also would be wise to quote the string used in the regexp with `\Q` and `\E`, e.g. `grep { /\Q$ENV{REPLACEMENT}\E/i }`.