# Perl replace content of a file with variable

Tags: shell, perl

I have a `a.md` file:

````
Start file

```
replace content here by a variable or result of a command such as pwd,
the whole content in this code block should be something like /Users/danny/MyProjects/CurrentDir
```
End file
````

And a script in `update.sh` to update file above:

````bash
#!/bin/sh

t=$(pwd)
echo $t
perl -i -p0e 's/(?<=```shell\n)[\s\S]*(?=\n```)/$t/s' a.md
````

It works fine with a string but I cannot replace with a variable such as `$(pwd)`.

Comment: "_It works fine with a string but I cannot replace with a variable such as $(pwd)_" -- I don't understand -- it works with `/.../$t/` but you want to have `/.../$(pwd)/` ? (why?)  Or it works with a literal string but not with `$t`?

Comment: it add an empty line with `$t`.

Comment: "_it add an empty line with `$t`_" -- OK, thank you, as expected. (The Perl program there cannot see those shell variables, surprising as it may seem.  We have to specifically pass them to the program.) I posted an answer, let me know if there are questions (I'll add more to it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Perl command-line program in that shell script cannot use variables from the script just so but we need to pass variables to it somehow.

There are a few ways to do that,<sup>†</sup> and perhaps using [`-s` switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-s) is simplest here

````
#!/bin/bash

t=$(pwd)
echo $t
perl -i -0777 -s -pe's/(?<=```shell\n)[\s\S]*(?=\n```)/$d/s' -- -d="$t" a.md

# or
# perl -i -0777 -s -pe'...' -- -d="$(pwd)" a.md
````

The `-s` for perl enables a basic support for switches for the program itself.

So that `-d=...` becomes available as `$d` in the program, either with the assigned value, here the value of the bash variable `$t`, or `1` if not assigned (`-d`). We can pass multiple variables this way, each in its own switch.

The `--` after the program mark the start of arguments.

We do not need a shell variable but can directly use a command output, `-var="$(pwd)"`.

---

<sup>†</sup> Aside from using storage (files, databases, etc) or pipes, there are two more ways to directly pass arguments given to this command-line ("one-liner") program

- Pass the variable as an argument and read it from `@ARGV` in the program

  ```
  t=$(pwd)
  perl -i -0777 -s -pe'BEGIN { $d = shift }; s/.../$d/s' "$t" a.md
  ```

  We need to also *remove* it from `@ARGV` so that the files can then be processed, which is what [shift](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift) does, and need to do this in a `BEGIN` block since `-p` sets a loop.
- Export a variable in bash making it an environment variable and a Perl script can then use that via [`%ENV` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#%25ENV)

  ```
  export t=$(pwd)
  perl -i -0777 -s -pe's/.../$ENV{t}/s' a.md
  ```

  Note, it's `t` in the `%ENV` hash (`$ENV{t}`), the name of the variable, not `$t` (value)

See for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51713578/4653379) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62208364/4653379)

Comment: Yeah so we can assign the value by adding the flags like `-d="$(pwd)`. Appreciate it man!

Comment: @Danny Yes (and can do multiple ones, `-d="$(pwd)", -var="other" ...`).  I added to the answer two other ways to do it, and a couple of links.