# How do I get a SECONDS variable in Perl from bash?

Tags: bash, perl

How do I display basic variables like `SECONDS` inside Perl while running command in bash?

```
perl -e 'system(bash -c echo $SECONDS)'
```

It displays nothing at all. I have no access to the bash variables, but I am running a Perl command in bash.

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What is it that you’re _really_ trying to achieve?

Comment: I don’t think `$SECONDS` is exported (because that wouldn’t make any sense), so Perl won’t see it. But if I understand correctly you’re running Bash inside Perl inside Bash. Which Bash’s `$SECONDS` do you want?

Comment: Why wouldn't it make sense to print seconds? I am obviously running Perl inside the bash. And therefore I want to use bash. I don't want to reinvent the wheel every time.

Comment: What would the exported value of `$SECONDS` be, since it changes all the time? When you run `system(bash -c echo $SECONDS)`, do you want `$SECONDS` to be expanded by (the outer) Bash, by Perl or by (the inner) Bash? If it‘s the last option, then won’t it always print `0`? And if it’s not, then why are you calling Bash (again) at all?!

Comment: That's the core of programming, that you get a non-static value from variable and can return the value between different programs, programming languages and system. Everything else is pointless.

Comment: @CuriousPanda A common way to share a variable between programs, especially processes that are parent and child, is environment variables. A parent can export a variable for a child to read, but once exported it holds a _static_ value. `$SECONDS` in Bash is a ‘special’ variable whose value changes all the time. Not all variables are exported (they’re variables, but not _environment_ variables), and _I_ don’t think it makes much sense to export `$SECONDS`. But once again; what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: SECONDS reports the number of seconds since `bash` started, so it will be zero if you start a new `bash` process that prints it... which seems pointless. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @CuriousPanda I think there is some confusion here. The bash variable `SECONDS` indicates how long the current bash-invocation is running. Calling this variable within a different bash-child does not make much sense from a programmatic point of view as a child should never know how old it's parent is. Furthermore, `SECONDS` is a special variable that only gets updated when referenced within the bash-invocation. So even by exporting it, it would be incorrect. What you could do is pass the content of `SECONDS` at the start of the perl invocation to perl, and in perl, add the perl runtime to it.

Comment: `time - $^T` will give you the seconds since *perl* started, which you can then combine with an exported bash `SECONDS` variable to get the total time that has passed since the bash script that launched the perl script started. Not sure how else it could be useful to have available.

Comment: The immediate problem with your code is that both `system()` and `bash -c` need to be passed single strings, which need to be quoted... and since there's going to be a string (the bash command passed to `bash -c`) inside a string (the arg to `system()`) inside a string (the perl script passed to `perl -e`) the quotes and escapes get messy: `perl -e 'system("bash -c \"echo \$SECONDS\"")'`. But, as @Biffen pointed out this just prints "0", since the new instance of bash that `system()` creates has been running for 0 seconds. So the real question is, what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: `system(bash -c echo $SECONDS)` is not even valid Perl. It would invoke a function names `bash`. You should get a syntax error from this.

Comment: I don't see what "needs details or clarity" here (reason for closing) -- They want to be able to use (pre-defined) bash variables in a Perl subprocess ... looks clear to me?  It's so clear in fact that similar questions have been asked many times and this is probably a dupe, but then we should find a corresponding page (for how to use _defined shell variables_, not just any) and close it that way.  In the meanwhile, voting to reopen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bash variable need be exported so that a Perl program, executed in that same bash process, can see it.  Then you can use it in Perl as an environment variable, or in a subshell

```
echo $SECONDS                                    # 14  (newly opened terminal)
export SECONDS

perl -wE'say $ENV{SECONDS}'                      # 23

perl -wE'system "bash", "-c", "echo \$SECONDS"'  # 23
```

Note that the `$` character need be escaped otherwise the Perl program will consider the `$SECONDS` to be a variable of its own. and will try to evaluate it (to no avail) before it passes arguments to `system` for a shell that it starts.

---

The question was raised of how to pass this only to that one program. Then pass the value as a command-line argument to the Perl program?  See how to pass shell variables to Perl one-liners for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62208364/4653379).

Yet another way to make this value available only to the invoked program, contributed by `Cyrus` in a comment, is

```
SECONDS=$SECONDS perl -wE'say $ENV{SECONDS}'
```

Also, now once a new variable is introduced one can name it more suitably for the Perl program, since it won't anymore behave like the bash's `SECONDS`.  Like

```
SHELL_ELAPSED=$SECONDS perl -wE'say $ENV{SHELL_ELAPSED}'
```

Comment: I know the export trick, but isn't that a security risk? I want to pass the command aka variable aka string only to specific process, not all processes. The problem is really that one can only work with strings.

Comment: @CuriousPanda "_I want to pass the command aka variable aka string only to specific process..._"  -- Can pass it as an (command-line) argument to that specific program then?    Otherwise, local variables aren't seen in a subshell -- have to export them (make them global)

Comment: @Shawn  "_missing a closing single quote_" -- indeed, thank you, fixed

Comment: @CuriousPanda Also, if you elaborate on what you need `SECONDS` for in the Perl program (by editing the question is best) I can expand this answer accordingly

Comment: @CuriousPanda "_I know the export trick, but isn't that a security risk?_" -- exporting a variable need not be a security problem.  Exporting functions has a history of that kind, since it was written as a command string in a variable, but then that was changed ... still, exporting a function _can_, perhaps and under specific circumstances, be exploited.  I am not aware of a specific (and realistic) possibility for a problem with exporting a variable/

Comment: `SECONDS=$SECONDS perl ...`?

Comment: @Cyrus ... you mean define the variable at the same line etc? Yeah, can do that too, and only this program sees it.  That answers their follow-up question

Comment: @CuriousPanda  See the solution from Cyrus in a comment just above -- define a variable and _at the same line_ (no semicolons or such!) invoke the program.  That way the value for `SECONDS` is made available in the Perl program, and only in that program

Comment: @CuriousPanda And once we are defining a variable you can now name it more suitably than `SECONDS` for Perl (since it won't behave like bash's `SECONDS` does anymore)

Comment: @Cyrus Added that to the answer, thank you

Comment: @CuriousPanda  Added to the answer.  Fyi, I had also added a link to another post that shows ways to pass a shell variables to a Perl command-line program ("one-liner")